# How to stream videos from firebase cloud storage instead of downloading the whole video file

Tags: android, video, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Been Google searching to understand this concept but not getting a definite answer,I want to know if using getdownloadurl() in firebase cloud storage for videos will let the videos get streamed bit by bit instead of downloading all the video files at once,i also want to know if firebase is not the best option for such.
What I'm trying to do is to create an android app where videos uploaded by other users can be streamed but I don't want the videos to be downloaded once after request I need the video to get downloaded bit by bit and change quality based on network connection as the video is being watched as opposed to downloading all the videos at once which would be really slow.

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not support any A/V streaming or transcoding protocols.  It only supports full sequential object downloads.  While you can certainly "stream" video over an HTTP download, it will play back only as fast as the original object can be downloaded, starting from the beginning of the object, and you will not be able to scrub forward or backward in the media beyond what has already been transferred.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the native VideoView object in Android?  This example has a static URL like the one you would get from Firebase: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-play-video-from-url-in-android/

Obviously, you would need to go out and fetch the "download URL" first and then use it as your source.

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Your Video URL
    String videoUrl = "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20201217192146/Screenrecorder-2020-12-17-19-17-36-828.mp4?_=1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // finding videoview by its id
        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        // Uri object to refer the
        // resource from the videoUrl
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        
        // sets the resource from the
        // videoUrl to the videoView
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        
        // creating object of
        // media controller class
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        
        // sets the anchor view
        // anchor view for the videoView
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        
        // sets the media player to the videoView
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        
        // sets the media controller to the videoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        
        // starts the video
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the implication of this is that it is not the job of the host, ie Firebase, to decide whether you would like to download the full file or stream it. That is the role of the client.